# How to set Timeout value for Session

Tags: asp.net, session

Wat is the default value for session timout? And how and where can I set the timeout value for session??? Plz, tell me in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default 20 minutes which is reset with each request

```
Include this in you web.config file:

<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="540"/>
```

REad this forum for more:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx).

```
<sessionState timeout="number of minutes" ...>
    <providers>...</providers>
</sessionState>
```

The default is 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is 20 minutes. You can set it in the [sessionState's timeout attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx).